# Using Hibernate Reactive Panache with SDKs that switch thread

Tags: locking, redisson, quarkus-panache

I'm using Reactive Panache for Postgresql. I need to take an application level lock(redis), inside which I need to perform certain operations. However, panache library throws the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: HR000069: Detected use of the reactive Session from a different Thread than the one which was used to open the reactive Session - this suggests an invalid integration; original thread [222]: 'vert.x-eventloop-thread-3' current Thread [154]: 'vert.x-eventloop-thread-2'
```

My code looks something like this:

```
redissonClient.getLock("lock").lock(this.leaseTimeInMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, this.lockId)
.chain(() ->  return Panache.withTransaction(() -> Uni.createFrom.nullItem())
                            .eventually(lock::release);
)
```

Solutions such as the ones mentioned in [this](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-reactive/issues/1194) issue show the correct use with AWS SDK but not when used in conjunction with something like redisson. Does anyone have this working with redisson?

Update:

I tried the following on lock acquire and release:

```
.runSubscriptionOn(MutinyHelper.executor(Vertx.currentContext())
```

This fails with the following error even though I have `quarkus-vertx` dependency added:

```
Cannot invoke "io.vertx.core.Context.runOnContext(io.vertx.core.Handler)" because "context" is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Panache might not be the best choice in this case.

I would try using Hibernate Reactive directly:

```
@Inject
Mutiny.SessionFactory factory;

...

redissonClient.getLock("lock")
    .lock(this.leaseTimeInMillis,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, this.lockId)
    .chain(() -> factory.withTransaction(session -> Uni.createFrom.nullItem())
                            .eventually(lock::release))
```

Comment: Tried that as well. I get the following error: 

[Exception 0] java.lang.IllegalStateException: The current operation requires a safe (isolated) Vert.x sub-context, but the current context hasn't been flagged as such. You can still use Hibernate Reactive, you just need to avoid using the methods which implicitly require accessing the stateful context, such as MutinySessionFactory#withTransaction and #withSession.

Comment: I think the best thing to do is to create an issue (ideally with a test case) here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues